Inline editing for lookup field on LWC
On account I added LWC with that I want to inline edit contact related fields. On contact I have Sub Contact which is self lookup to contact. in My data table On Sub_Contact__c  it showing recordId instead of name and not getting that lookup search and also not getting  Sub_Contact__r.FirstName value on UI. Below is my Code
Apex Controller : AccountRelatedContactsController
public with sharing class AccountRelatedContactsController {

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)

    public static List<Contact> getContacts(Id accountId) {

        try {

            return [

                SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Sub_Contact__r.FirstName,Sub_Contact__c,Email, Name

                FROM Contact

                WHERE Id IN (

                    SELECT ContactId

                    FROM AccountContactRelation

                    WHERE AccountId = :accountId

                )

            ];

        } catch (Exception e) {

            throw new AuraHandledException('Error retrieving contacts: ' + e.getMessage());

        }

    }

    @AuraEnabled

    public static void updateContacts(List<Contact> contacts) {

        try {

            update contacts;

        } catch (Exception e) {

            throw new AuraHandledException('Error updating contacts: ' + e.getMessage());

        }

    }

}

LWC  : contactListComponent.html
<template>

    <lightning-card title="Acc Contacts" icon-name="standard:contact">        

        <lightning-datatable

            key-field="Id"

            data={contacts}

            columns={columns}

            draft-values={draftValues}

            onsave={handleSave}>

        </lightning-datatable>

    </lightning-card>

</template>

contactListComponent.js
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';

import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';

import getContacts from '@salesforce/apex/AccountRelatedContactsController.getContacts';

import updateContacts from '@salesforce/apex/AccountRelatedContactsController.updateContacts';

import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

export default class MiContactList extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;

    @track draftValues = [];

    @track contacts;

    wiredContactsResult;

    @track columns = [

        {

            label: 'Name',

            fieldName: 'contactLink',

            type: 'url',

            typeAttributes: { label: { fieldName: 'Name' }, target: '_blank' }

        },

        { label: 'First bName', fieldName: 'FirstName', editable: true },

        { label: 'Last Name', fieldName: 'LastName', editable: true },

        { label: 'Sub Contact', fieldName: 'Sub_Contact__c', type:'lookupColumn', editable: true },

        { label: 'Sub Con Name', fieldName: 'Sub_Contact__c.FirstName', editable: false },

        { label: 'Email', fieldName: 'Email', editable: true }

    ];

    @wire(getContacts, { accountId: '$recordId' })

    wiredContacts(result) {

        this.wiredContactsResult = result;

        if (result.data) {

            this.contacts = result.data.map(contact => {

                return { ...contact, contactLink: `/${contact.Id}` };

            });

        } else if (result.error) {

            this.showToast('Error', result.error.body.message, 'error');

        }

    }

    handleChange( event ) {

        console.log(event.detail.recordId);

        }

    handleSave(event) {

        const updatedFields = event.detail.draftValues;

        updateContacts({ contacts: updatedFields })

            .then(() => {

                this.showToast('Success', 'Contacts updated successfully', 'success');

                this.draftValues = [];

                return refreshApex(this.wiredContactsResult);

            })

            .catch(error => {

                this.showToast('Error', error.body.message, 'error');

            });

    }

    showToast(title, message, variant) {

        const event = new ShowToastEvent({

            title: title,

            message: message,

            variant: variant

        });

        this.dispatchEvent(event);

    }

}



To use the type "lookupColumn", you would need to implement a custom data type. This involves extending the standard lightning-datatable component. How to do this is in the documentation linked above. It's not complicated, but does require a bit of code.
As for the second part, relationships are not automatically navigated through, which means Sub_Contact__c.FirstName is looking for an object property that looks like { "Sub_Contact__C.FirstName": "Brian" }, but you're receiving the data as { "Sub_Contact__r": { "FirstName": "Brian" } }. You need to flatten the data.
